# .NET MAUI WebAuthenticatorResult not working for Strava

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui, strava

I am creating a .NET MAUI app that is going to get some data from the Strava API.
When I try to use the WebAuthenticatorResult class to get the access token, passing the URI and the callbackURI I get the following error:

[Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMQFY.png)

The code I am using is this:

[Code I am trying to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo77z.png)

On Strava, my authorization callback domain is set to literally "myapp.com".

When I try to URL directly on the browser it works (sorry, it is in portugues):

[success when trying directly on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkzWS.png)

Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Doesn’t the first image already tell you what to do?

Comment: If I had experience on this kind of thing, maybe. Can you give me a tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check part [Get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android#get-started) of document [Xamarin.Essentials: Web Authenticatorenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android) ,you will find that:

> Android requires an Intent Filter setup to handle your callback
> URI. This is easily accomplished by subclassing the
> `WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity` class:

```
const string CALLBACK_SCHEME = "myapp";

[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataScheme = CALLBACK_SCHEME)]
public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
{
}
```

And if your project's Target Android version is set to `Android 11 (R API 30)` you must update your Android Manifest with queries that are used with the new [package visibility](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility) requirements.

Open the `AndroidManifest.xml` file under the Properties folder and add the following inside of the manifest node:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

For more details, you can check:[Xamarin.Essentials: Web Authenticator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android).